# Pandas: Create a binary column randomly but with specific proportions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a new random binary column in my table and it needs to have 60% of values as 1 and 40% of values as 0. I have tried to use the np.random.choice function from the numpy package like the following, however, the proportion changes everytime I run my code.

```
np.random.choice(a = [0,1], size = len(df), p = [0.4, 0.6])
```

I need to have these proportions fixed. Can anyone help how it can be done? Thank you!

Comment: You should provide a reproduceable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Why do you think the proportion changes?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create an numpy array of size 100 with the distribution of 1 and 0 that you wanted and store it in variable `m`:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.random.choice(a = [0,1], size = 100, p = [0.4, 0.6])
```

I don't know anything about your pandas data frame, because you didn't post your source code here. Therefore I can't tell you, why `len(df)` is different each time.